# Unable to cast HttpContext to User

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication, jwt

I'm using Web API. I have followed a tutorial on implementing JWT Auth. When I use Postman and when I get the token and try to do authentication it works but I'm unable to cast the `HttpContext` to `User` class.

Error:

> "Unable to cast object of type
> 'AsyncStateMachineBox1[TechStore.Api.Data.Enteties.User,TechStore.Api.Data.Repositories.GenericRepository1+d__5[TechStore.Api.Data.Enteties.User]]'
> to type 'TechStore.Api.Data.Enteties.User'."

On authorise method:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"]; //Here it throws error
 
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
            }
        }
```

The data is correct in the httpcontext but I can't cast it to user object.

User Class:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Adress { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Cart Cart { get; set; }

        public int CartId { get; set; }
    }
```

JWTAuthntictor class:

```
namespace TechStore.Api.Helpers
{
    public class JWTAuthenticator
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public JWTAuthenticator
            (
                RequestDelegate next
            )
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IRepository<User> userService)
        {
            var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

            if (token != null)
                attachUserToContext(context, userService, token);

            await _next(context);
        }

        private void attachUserToContext(HttpContext context, IRepository<User> userService, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("acdc11434jjkk34311acdasdwjkdnovjfnbcacacasdadc11434jjkk314311acdc");
                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
                var userId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);

                // attach user to context on successful jwt validation
                context.Items["User"] = userService.GetByProperty(u => u.Id == userId);
            }
            catch
            {
                // do nothing if jwt validation fails
                // user is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Athorize attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public AuthorizeAttribute()
        {
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
 
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the expected object without casting? the same properties? types? values? `var user = context.HttpContext.Items["User"];`

Comment: Is JSON response properly getting decrypted to match the c# class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same situation.
for me this line:

```
var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
```

did work on a NET Core 3.1 project,
but in a different project with NET Core 5 I got this exact exception.

if you just need to check that the user is not null, than you do not need to cast the
context items to a `User` object.

instead you could do this and your if check will work:

```
        //var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
        var user = context.HttpContext.Items["User"];//remove casting
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
        }
```

what i could not figure out is how to access the result (which is the actual object you might want) in the attached image.
[image]

maybe some one else could clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

The Items["User"] is a [Task<TResult> class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-6.0) with the result property having User object.

That's why, you cannot cast directly to the User model. You need to get the Task result property first, which stores your `User` object.

What you need to do is to cast `context.HttpContext.Items["User"];`  to `Task<User>`
You cannot cast it into [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0) without a known type, it doesn't have a Result property, meaning casting without `TResult`, the result property would disappear.

This is the code:

```
var task = (Task<User>)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
var user = task.Result;
```

Looking at Kifka's screenshot, the Result object is already an User object, so no further casting is required. `var user` will be of `User` type.